# Why are enum-style unions treated as a class in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, f#, clr, discriminated-union

I realize that discriminated unions are not necessarily the same as enums. But in the case of these types of DUs:

```
type Colors = Red | Green | Blue
```

They are treated as a class `Colors` where each color is a readonly property referring to a instance of the `Colors` class.

For these type of DUs that can be likened to enums, why are they not treated as enums in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have an enum in F# if you define it like this:

```
type Colors = Red = 1 | Green = 2 | Blue = 3
```

Discriminated unions are seen as classes in C# because that's how they are encoded by the compiler - as a class for the union type and a set of nested classes for the cases. This is what all the non-F# clients of your code see - this unfortunately includes the times you access discriminated unions using .NET reflection API in F#.

Unions are represented by classes because of complex cases that can carry arbitrary arguments - this is a natural way to encode them. I guess a point can be made that for a scenario where all cases have no arguments the compiler could generate an enum instead. But this would make the compiled representation for unions heterogeneous in a very crazy way - starting from the fact that simple unions would be value types and complex unions would be reference types. The number of pitfalls this would add to the language would be disastrous!

Comment: I suspect the main reason these DUs are not enums is that the behaviour when new elements are added in the middle would break compatibility in weird ways.

Comment: The idea seems pretty harmless on the surface, but when you think about it, there are really no benefits of them being enums - not even performance ones - over than making C# API a bit nicer. And this can already be done by declaring an enum in F# on your own.

Answer (score 4):

Enumerations are conceptually distinct from F# discriminated unions, as they are *extensible*.

The following is a valid declaration and usage of a CLI enum from F#. The resulting enum is compatible with C#:

```
type A = Alpha = 1 | Alice = 2
let a = enum<A>(56)
```

Compare with a similar DU:

```
type B = Beta | Bob
// No way to instantiate B except the above cases
```

Thus, even in cases where it is possible, compiling a DU as an enum would render it less strict than expected of a DU. As should be expected, the following gives a warning:

```
// Compiler warning: incomplete pattern matches.
match a with A.Alpha -> '!' | A.Alice -> '?'
```